# How To Know The Client Url in Wso2ESB sing property Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i have two proxys . i wish to filter the Client url in second proxy means
my first proxy implemented and send some data to 2nd proxy.Its working fine But my wish i dont want allow any other service to use my proxy .In that case i need to filter based On the URL. We have option in ESb get-property('To') for know to url of target service but How we can know that Which client is calling me

```
`<property name="client-host" expression="get-property('From')"/>`
```

this property not working
even i defined in Client and target service also but its returning "null"

```
<property name="client-host" expression="get-property('To')"/>
```

this property returning me present service URl

But i need Client Url Who is calling me...
how could i define it and where can i define either in Client Or Target
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Property+Mediator#PropertyMediator-PropertiesToFromActionFaultToReplyToMessageID

Answer (score 0):

can you enable the ws-addressing module to your  proxies and see that "from" property is working or not?
Generally from,to action properties are captured from  transport receiver..
WS-addressing will capture same properties and if they are already available, ws-addressing will overwrite them...

Comment: where can i found this ws-addressing in my proxy.if i find i may enabled in client proxy are target proxy..

Comment: you can go via service dashboard of the proxy and modules section and enable it

Comment: i found it but it have 6 option which one i need to enable and i need to enable in client service or target service

Comment: i found this on that module page                                 Service Level           Service Group Level        Global level
No engaged modules found   No engaged modules found addressing-4.0